# Javascript preventing the submit button to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a js that acts as a *"fade" page transition*:

```
jQuery('body').css('display','none');

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('body').fadeIn();
    jQuery('a').on('click',function(event){
        var thetarget = this.getAttribute('target')

        if (thetarget !="_blank" ) {
            var thehref = this.getAttribute('href')

            event.preventDefault();
            console.log(thehref)
            if(thehref){
                console.log('not null')
                jQuery('body').fadeOut(function(){
                    window.location = thehref
                });
            }
        }
    });
});

setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery('body').fadeIn();
},1000)
```

and I have this form:

```
<form id = "create_faculty_formcontainer" action = "" method = "post">
    <input type = "text" name = "fac_idnumber" placeholder="ID Number" required/><br/><br/>
    <input type = "text" name = "fac_firstname" placeholder="First Name" required/><br/><br/>
    <input type = "text" name = "fac_lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required/><br/><br/>

    <input type = "password" id = "password_fac" name = "fac_password" placeholder="Password" required/>

    <br/>

    <input type = "submit" name = "fac_submit" value = "       sign up       ">
</form>
```

Whenever I click the submit button, nothing happens. So I tried erasing my javascript and the button worked. The js must have been causing the submit button not to work and I couldn't actually figured what is it or how to fix it. 
Any thoughts on how can I keep the javascript and make the submit button work too?

Comment: the javascript snippet you've pasted does not seem to block/stop any action on submit button

Comment: I have another form up top the form I pasted and that form worked despite having the javascript. I really don't know what's wrong. There are 3 forms in the page. The first one worked, while the other won't. I checked and they are all the same in code.

Comment: event.preventDefault(); is killing the events tied to that click.

Comment: @Korgrue so I'll just erase the `event.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: That `event.preventDefault()` shouldn't be affecting a form submit. Your submit button isn't an `a` tag. More likely than not it is an `event.preventDefault()` somewhere, that's just not the right event.

Comment: Brian, I apologize but I am going to have to disagree with you. His submission handler is that click event that he is preventing prop on. Guarantee if he removes that preventDefault that the form works.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. 
Erasing the `event.preventDefault();` settles it.
Thanks to Korgrue